# Trigger.io Can't point to certificate. /usr/bin/codesign: iPhone Developer: no identity found

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl-certificate, trigger.io

I'm trying to run on the device. I have just downloaded my certificate from the developers member center. I've added it to my key chain. I've tried many possible certificate names through the toolkit UI. I've tried pointing the toolkit at the .cert file and trying many different cert names. It when viewing the debug output it dosen't look like trigger even passes a cert path parameter to code sign. What am I missing?

```
[DEBUG] Provisioning profile has valid wildcard application ID
[INFO] Plist OK
[INFO] 1 Provisioned Device(s):
[INFO] ['96fdb503d1deade5d1455288331543c3134577ef']
[DEBUG] Running: '/usr/bin/codesign' '--force' '--preserve-metadata' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/w1/3zw7h2xs0jbdw5_2f96q0v700000gn/T/tmp2AO4Hq' '--sign' 'Kev Zettler' '--resource-rules=/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/development/ios/device-ios.app/ResourceRules.plist' '/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/development/ios/device-ios.app'
[DEBUG] Kev Zettler: no identity found
[ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: Kev Zettler: no identity found
[DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/async.py", line 106, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/trigger/api/app.py", line 312, in run
    forge_main.run(['--general.interactive', 'no'])
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/main.py", line 435, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/customer_goals.py", line 136, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py", line 334, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py", line 293, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/ios_tasks.py", line 686, in run_ios
    certificate_password=certificate_password,
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/ios_tasks.py", line 578, in run_idevice
    entitlements_file=temp_file_path,
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/ios_tasks.py", line 354, in _sign_app
    path_to_app)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/checkiday-mobile/.template/generate_dynamic/module_dynamic/utils.py", line 346, in run_shell
    output=state.output.getvalue()
ShellError: Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: Kev Zettler: no identity found
```

local_config.json

```
{
    "general": {},
    "ios": {
        "profiles": {
            "DEFAULT": {
                "provisioning_profile": "/Users/kevzettler/Desktop/iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile.mobileprovision",
                "developer_certificate": "Kev Zettler"
            }
        },
        "simulatorsdk": "7.0",
        "simulatorfamily": "iphone",
        "device": "device"
    },
    "android": {
        "profiles": {
            "DEFAULT": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots of certs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq7XZ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually regenerated my certificate and provisioning profile on the apple member site and did everything again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The input area in the Trigger Toolkit titled `Certificate` should only contain the certificate name, not a path. Right now your certificate name is set to `iPhone Developer`. Make sure this reflects the certificate name in the member center. Also make sure that you are using the appropriate type of certificate - development vs. distribution.

The input area in the Trigger Toolkit titled `Provisioning Profile` should contain a path - one that points to your provisioning profile which should also be of the appropriate type as above.

Additionally, I would make sure your `local_config.json` reflects the proper path in addition to the toolkit UI.

If this doesn't work, including your local._config.json might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I added my local_config.json and some screenshots of my cert on the members center and locally from my keychain

Comment: Have you tried configuring everything with a distribution certificate and matching provisioning profile. I'm not sure what else to suggest, you seem to be doing everything properly.

Comment: I think the screenshot link should read 'screencloud.net/…' rather than 'screenbutt.net…'